# Nested Cron jobs in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, cron

I'm having a 'Tournament' sql table that contains start_time and end_time for my  tournaments. I also have another table which has playerId and tournamentIds so I can tell which players playes in which tournament. 
What I'm trying to do is to run a cron task to check my tournament table and see if tournament has ended so it can check players results from an external api. The problem is the external API has rate limit and I have to send my requestes every 1.5 sec.

What I tried to do is to write a cron job for every 10 seconds to check my tournament table (I couldn't come up with anyother solution rather than keep checking db):

```
cron.job("*/10 * * * * *", function(){
    result = Query tournament table Where EndTime=<Now && EndTime+10second>=Now
    if(result is not empty)
    {
      cron.job("*/1.5 * * * * *",function(){
           send API requests for that userId
            parse & store result in db
      });
    }
});
```

I don't feel right about this and it seems so buggy to me. Because the inner cron job might take longer than 10 seconds. Is there any good solution to do this. I'm using ExpressJS & MySQL.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good solution to this other than making the outer job not so strict on running every 10 seconds, and instead running, 10 seconds after the last run finished or similar.

Comment: @KevinB then how can I know that end_time has arrived so I can start checking?

Comment: i don't understand, rephrase please? what does end_time have to do with the question?

Comment: @KevinB I only have to start sending api request when tournament deadline is reached. for example lets say TournamentA's endtime is at 2:00pm. What I'm doing there is checking every 10 seconds to see it it is 2:00pm yet. If it is I start sending api requests every 1.5 second

Comment: Right, whatever you're doing to do that you should continue doing, since you included that logic as a comment in your question, I assume you already have that. If not then... i'm not going to be of much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing can be solved with event emitters. There is a very useful module node-schedule in npm which can help you in this scenario that you are telling. What you have to do is is to schedule a job to fire at the deadline of the project, that job will hit the 3rd party api and check for results.You an schedule a job like this

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
schedule.scheduleJob("jobName", "TimeToFire", function () {
//Put your api hit here.

//finally remove the schedule
if ("jobName" in schedule.scheduledJobs) {
schedule.scheduledJobs["jobName"].cancel();
delete schedule.scheduledJobs["jobName"];
                        }
})
```

Make sure you store all the jobs scheduled in the database also as a server crash will invalidate all the schedules that you have scheduled and will have to reschedule them again.

Comment: I tried this but i want to call my api every 1.5 second. I used setTimeout() but it doesn't work in a loop. What I'm doing is query my database get all upcoming projects, create a schduleJob for them. each sechuduled job should call my api every 1.5

Comment: Well you can schedule jobs by creating a rule, in your case that will be 1.5 secs apart then you just have to specify that rule in place of the timeToFire text in the example code. For more information regarding the rule thing you can refer to the original documentation for node-schedule